# Correct way to handle .wasm.gz and .data files in Django?

Tags: python, django, webassembly

I'm currently dealing with a problem in my django web application that is running locally on 192.168.0.168. I'm making use of an OCR library that makes use of .wasm.gz files and .data files. In the documentation they mention: " In some cases you need to configure your webserver to serve data and wasm.gz files.". My first idea was to add the following mimetypes in django:

1. mimetypes.add_type("application/x-gzip", ".wasm.gz", True)
2. mimetypes.add_type("application/octet-stream", ".data", True)

I'm however still seeing the error: [error wasm-instantie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY46L.jpg). It somehow can't instantiate wasm because django needs to serve the wasm.gz and .data files correctly. These have been added however to the static folder and I'm able to download them if I manually browse to the link. Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to serve these correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If the library you're using loads WASM code with `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming`, the WASM files must be served with the `application/wasm` content type.
GZip is a content *encoding* rather than the media type.

I'm assuming you're using the dev server, so if the above is the problem then you should replace the first line of code above with:

`mimetypes.add_type("application/wasm", ".wasm.gz", True)`

(Note that the above is only necessary when running Python versions pre 3.8. If you're running Python 3.8 or later then this is not your solution.)

To clarify, it's fairly common practice to pre-compress static assets with GZip, which are then sent over HTTP with the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header set. This saves server resources compressing the file every time it's requested.
When set up properly, the browser receives the GZipped bytes, decompresses them, and interprets the decompressed bytes as the appropriate Content-Type.

The Django dev server defers to the built in `mimetypes` package, which does this testing.